Question on the effect of oil price on inflation through exchange rate effect
In oil-exporting countries, oil price increases lead to decrease in inflation through the effect of exchange rate appreciation.
Please theoretically explain the underlying reason for this issue.
For example, increase in oil price leads to exchange rate appreciation, which results in domestic inflation. Why?

An exchange rate appreciation (your currency can now buy more of a foreign currency) can result in reductions in the domestic prices of some imported goods.
